# MIPS - how to convert a float input into integer without using conversion instructions ,and use either shift or rotate only?

Tags: mips

```
li $v0, 4         # system call code for Print String 
la $a0, prompt    # load address of prompt into $a0 
syscall           # print the prompt message 
li $v0, 6         # system call code for Read float
syscall           # reads the value of N into $v0 
cvt.w.s $f0,$f0
```

so instead of using cvt.w.s, how can i change floating point into integer? also is there any way can check if the user input is/isn't a float?